# How to install apache Storm on windows 7

Tags: apache-storm, bigdata

Can anyone tell me that how can i install apache storm on windows 7 ?
I am new to big data  so need a little help.

Answer (score 0):

Please explain what does not work. Storm is Java + Python so setting up on Windows should not be a problem. Zookeeper run on Windows just fine. There are many Vagrant / Docker implementations that will work as well. So what problem are you trying to resolve? 
BTW, if you are trying to set it up for development, you dont need a cluster. You can run it with local cluster settings. (check storm documentation)

The general steps are:

1. Download Zookeeper
2. Untar and configure single node cluster
3. Download Storm
4. Follow Storm documentation and configure Nimbus/Supervisor settings
5. Follow Storm documentation to start Nimbus, Supervisor, Storm UI and Log Viewer.

Make sure you read documentation of 0.10.0 and 1.0.x These releases are not compatible and some of the libs you may want to use will not work with the new Storm release.

Comment: Thanks yarik, i have downloaded the things you said up there. now i want to know that how i will store that and process it with storm? like in previous i was using Sql server. and there i was saving the data in the software and getting the data from there by writing queries. but now i dont know where do i put data and access data. i have lots of text files and data in it.

Comment: I think it is a separate question and you should explain what you are trying to do. Kafka and store deals with stream data sounds like you need to handle data at rest as well.